Освобождение памяти от картинок в ListBox
У меня есть листбокс, элементы которого являются мною написанным классом. У этих элементов есть название и картинка(путь).
Я столкнулся с такой проблемой, что когда я очищаю и пересобираю листбокс новыми элементами, старые остаются в памяти и со временем засоряют ее. Из-за этого новые картинки грузятся все медленнее и медленнее.
Прикладываю код:
<StackPanel x:Name="StackUpListBox" Height="200">
                    <ListBox x:Name="GamesListBox" Height="200">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding image}" Width="50" Height="50" Margin="3"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне очищать вручную старые элементы листбокса из памяти?
Вот по какому принципу идет наполнение листбокса элементами:
            GamesListBox.Items.Clear();
            var select = GamesCatgs.SelectedItem;
            string FilePath = $"Jsons\\Category{select}.json";

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FilePath))
            {
                string json = sr.ReadToEnd();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
                {
                    allGames = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GameItem>>(json);
                    displayedCount = 0;
                    AddGamesToListBox();
                }
            }

private void AddGamesToListBox()
        {
            int countToAdd = Math.Min(10, allGames.Count - displayedCount);

            for (int i = 0; i < countToAdd; i++)
            {
                GamesListBox.Items.Add(allGames[displayedCount]);
                displayedCount++;
            }
        }



Научитесь использовать привязки, у вас не должно быть в коде такого GamesListBox.Items.Add(..);, у вас вообще не должно быть обращения к UI элементам через код, не должно быть x:Name. Все, что у вас должно быть, это коллекция, например public ObservableCollection<GameItem> Items { get; } = []; и далее привязанный к ней UI (<ListBox Items = "{Binding Items}" />). 2. StreamReader тут бесполезен, и я сказал-бы даже вреден, достаточно File.ReadAllText(...). Вот исправив это, у вас проблем быть не должно. Ну и + виртуализацию включите для оптимизации.


Можно пожалуйста про виртуализацию поподробнее?

Первая ссылка гугла по запросу WPF Виртуализация... Опять ленитесь!

Я подумал вы про другую виртуализацию, это уже нашел, спасибо.
Однако, ваше решение тоже не работает.
Предыдущие картинки все еще засоряют память, даже если их нет в листбоксе.

Ну тогда делайте минимальный, самодостаточный пример, который воспроизведет данную проблему. Ибо если я сейчас создам чистый WPF проект, создам класс с двумя свойствами, привяжу его, то у меня не будет ничего там замедляться и застревать в памяти...

Виртуализация тут только хуже сделает и будет проблема. хотя она и так есть.

Провел тест. Простая привязанная коллекция с текстом и ссылками на изображения, все привязано в XAML. Без виртуализации: Общая картина, Добавление, Удаление (показываю только FileStream, ибо остальные объекты будут аналогичными, после сборщика. Как видите, в память было сразу загружено 100 изображений, а затем, после удаления, они были успешно выгружены полностью из памяти.

С виртуализацией: Общая, +100 (показываю только FileStream), прокрутка, -100. Тут как видите, ситуация чуть иная, в память загрузилось только 6 изображений, после прокрутки, объектов в памяти постоянно было в районе 9, ну а после удаления они все успешно выгрузились из памяти, даже сборщик не пригодился. Код, XAML как в вопросе. Так что, на чистом проекте проблем нет, поэтому и прошу самодостаточный пример.

@EvgeniyZ спасибо.
можете сделать ответ, я отмечу

Какой вы от меня ответ ожидаете? Что "не воспроизводится"? Ну, я против таких ответов...

Ответ про виртуализацию. Она не очищает картинки из памяти как только листбокс пересобирается, но в конце концов, через некоторое время(у меня так работает, не знаю нормальное ли это поведение) память очищается

Ник указывать не забывайте в комментариях, ибо вам-то приходят уведомления, ибо комментарии под вашим вопросом, а мне приходят только если указать ник. Касательно ответа, я не считаю ответ про виртуализацию правильным, ибо 1. Она у вас и так, по умолчанию включена должна быть. 2. Она не является решением вашей проблемы, ибо как вы сказали, "картинки грузятся все медленней и медленней", ну а такого просто быть не может, а это значит, что у вас там что-то еще, что мешает работать приложению правильно. Короче, считаете, что нашли решение, можете дать ответ самостоятельно, ну а я пасс...
